# Elasticsearch match string to field with fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to match a string to a field and only want to apply fuzziness.

For example, with these documents:

```
{ title: "replace oilfilter" }, { title: "replace motoroil" }
```

The following queries should match only the first document:

```
"Replace oilfilter", "Replace oilsfilter", "Replaze oilfilter"
```

The following queries should **NOT** match any document:

```
"replace", "oilfilter", "motoroil"
```

What I got so far is the following:

## index

I'm using the keyword analyzer so it sees the (potential) phrase as a single word, this way it does not match a document when searching for "replace" but it does find a document when searching for the exact term "Replace oilfilter".

```
    "mappings": {
        "blacklist": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## search

I've tried multiple queries to search the documents. I got close with the following query:

```
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "title",
            "fuzziness": "3",
            "query": query
        }
    }
```

## results

With this query the following are the results:

```
> "Replace oilfilter" (exact words)
< doc: { title: "replace oilfilter" }, score: 0.5753..
< doc: { title: "replace motoroil" }, score: 0.2876..

> "Replace iolfilter" (typo)
< doc: { title: "replace oilfilter" }, score: 0.2876..

> "oilfilter" (other term)
< doc: { title: "replace oilfilter" }, score: 0.2876..
```

## problem

The results aren't that bad, but I need the scores to be more accurate. The second query with only the simple typo should get a much higher score than the second result in the first query and the only result in the third query.

What I'm trying to achieve is that it matches the **whole** query against the **whole** field in the document, that's why I'm using keyword analyzer. On top of that I only want to apply some fuzziness.

Hope someone can shed some light on this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following search should achieve what you want:

```
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "replace oilfliter",
            "fuzziness": "3",
            "fields": [
              "title"
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "75%",
            "type": "most_fields"
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

You can increase the `minimum_should_match` to 100% if you want require a match on all the query terms no matter how long the query string is.

Comment: Perfect! The scores are way better now, looks like a combination of matching words and fuzziness. I can however remove the "bool" and "must" queries, this gives me the same results.. Do you happen to know why? What's the purpose of the "bool", "must", "multi_match" combination?Thanks!

Comment: I think the bool and must are just remnants of a larger search that I was using. If you add an extra section to your search to boost phrase query matches the must component acts a little like a pre-filter before the phrase match is applied to the subset of results that passed the 'must' stage. In your case you can remove this. Multi-match also means you can run the search over additional fields, not just 'title', if you wanted to.

Comment: @TimBaas if this answered your question, please consider upvoting / awarding the answer. Thanks.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the reminder and clarification on the bool/must properties!