# Elasticsearch doesn't find product when i have mistake in name

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried use elasticsearch to write websearch. I created 3 products in my products index

> 1. Ibuprom Max
> 2. Nurofen Max Forte
> 3. Gripex Max

when i use

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all: {}
    }
}
```

I received all records, buth when i use search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "Max"
        }
    }
}
```

I receive all match where is "Max", but when i change Max to Mxa or Mx then i don't receive nothing. From what I read, elasticsearch by default with a typo, should I find products with Max in the name, unless I'm doing something wrong? Just what?

Comment: use fuzzy query : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Comment: I used ```{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "name": {
             "value": "Max"
            }
        }
    }
}```

this find all match, but when i changed Max to Mxa, Maxs or something similar, then elasticsearch nothing find

Comment: have you tried setting a value for `fuzziness`? If you set `fuzziness` to 1 then `Maxs` should be returned but not `Mxa`, because `Maxs` has edit distance of 1 and `Mxa` has edit distance of 2 (i.e. 2 chars need to be changed).

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335835/elasticsearch-match-string-to-field-with-fuzziness) might be helpful

Comment: @HoomanBahreini i set fuzziness to 2 and all works, thanks :) Set fuzziness to auto is good idea?

Comment: Perfect... I am not sure... Elasticsearch generally comes with really good default settings and using `Auto` is definitely not a bad idea... in my case, I don't use fuzzy queries, because it was returning a lot of irrelevant results... the good thing is you can easily tune it as your application is built. Also [this document](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-optimization-fuzziness-performance) might help.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Ok :) thanks for help and answer :)